# What happens when 2 outposts become colony at the exact same turn?

Tags: endless-space-2

What happens when 2 outposts become colony at the exact same turn? Who will own the system?

[image]

Here is an exemple in my current game.

Comment: Did you find out what happens? I'm curious too

Comment: @Milk Unfortunately, I don't remember what happened exactly. Sorry. I usually comeback to tell the answer for others but I forgot this time...